# Jquery GridManager when refresh page button control multiply

Tags: jquery, typescript, angular

I added a gridmanager (jquery) to my project angular2 using typescript 
in my ngAfterViewInit I added this

```
 this.gm = jQuery("#content").gridmanager().data('gridmanager');
        this.canvas = this.gm.$el.find("#" + this.gm.options.canvasId);
        this.gm.initGlobalCustomControls();
```

to init my grid, so when I navigate to open again my div where I have the grid the button Add Edittable Region multiply every[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7tOF.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7tOF.png) time I navigate and come back to grid page I found that the button Add Edditable Refion multiplied

[image: this picture after two refresh]

```
gm.initDefaultButtons = function () {

            if (gm.options.colSelectEnabled) {
                gm.options.customControls.global_col.push(
                    {callback: gm.selectColClick, loc: 'top', iconClass: 'fa fa-square-o', title: 'Select Column'});
            }
            if (gm.options.editableRegionEnabled) {
                gm.options.customControls.global_col.push(
                    {callback: gm.addEditableAreaClick, loc: 'top', iconClass: 'fa fa-edit', title: 'Add Editable Region'});
            }
        };
```

this Method in gridmanager.js that add buttons wich multiply

Comment: What does "refresh page" and "navigate to open again" mean? Perhaps your code above is called twice? Did you check by adding some `console.log(...)` or similar?

Comment: for example where I exit I'm in a template page then I go to list of templates to open another template 
in this time the buttons multiply

where i put console.log and what show  ?

Comment: It doesn't matter what `console.log()` prints. We need to know how often it prints. "I exit I'm in a template page then I go to list of templates to open another template " What does that mean? Using a `routerLink`?

Comment: Yes I use routerLink for each navigation 
why only this two controls (check box and href) that multiply
(I'm not very good in english excuse me for that)